# How to make a confirmation box that can be used multiple times? Android

Tags: android

so I looked at over 20 questions and posts on the internet and cannot see a way of making a confirmation box outside of the code that has to be enabled or if the code is within it, it breaks all the variables outside of it...

Here was an attempt:

Confirm class:

```
public class Confirm_Delete extends DialogFragment {
    public interface Confirm_Delete_Listener {
        public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog);

        public void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog);
    }

public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        // Verify that the host activity implements the callback interface
        try {
            // Instantiate the NoticeDialogListener so we can send events to the
            // host
            mListener = (Confirm_Delete_Listener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            // The activity doesn't implement the interface, throw exception
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement Confirm_Delete_Listener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
        // 1. Instantiate an AlertDialog.Builder with its constructor
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        // 2. Chain together various setter methods to set the dialog
        // characteristics
        builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete?")
                .setTitle("Confirm")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                // Send the positive button event back to host
                                // activity
                                mListener
                                        .onDialogPositiveClick(Confirm_Delete.this);
                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton("cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                // User cancelled the dialog
                                // Send the negative button event back to the
                                // host activity
                                mListener
                                        .onDialogNegativeClick(Confirm_Delete.this);
                            }
                        });
        // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

Activity file: (I cannot implement the dialog fragment into my activity since it is implementing the onClickListener

```
// call delete
        if (v == delete_w1) {
DialogFragment newFragment = new Confirm_Delete();
            newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "missiles");

}


public class Confirmation extends FragmentActivity implements
            Confirm_Delete.Confirm_Delete_Listener {
        public void showNoticeDialog() {
            // Create an instance of the dialog fragment and show it
            DialogFragment dialog = new Confirm_Delete();
            dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Confirm_Delete");
        }

        // The dialog fragment receives a reference to this Activity through the
        // Fragment.onAttach() callback, which it uses to call the following
        // methods
        // defined by the NoticeDialogFragment.NoticeDialogListener interface
        @Override
        public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog) {
            // User touched the dialog's positive button

        }

        @Override
        public void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog) {

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Step #1: Remove all occurrences of `confirm`.

Step #2: Pass into `delete_confirm()` some sort of listener object, on which you call some method to provide the result of the user working with the dialog. You would call method(s) on this object from your two `onClick()` methods. Or, pass into the `delete_confirm()` method a pair of `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` objects, one each for your positive and negative buttons.

Please bear in mind that `create()` returns an instance of a configured `AlertDialog`. The dialog still needs to be shown via a `DialogFragment`. And even when you tell the `DialogFragment` to show the dialog, the dialog will not actually appear until sometime after you return control of the main application thread back to Android. There is no "blocking dialog" model in Android, whereby you call some method and execution stops until after the user responds to input. Everything in Android is event-driven; you need to process the results of the click events at the time they occur.

Comment: i am assuming you mean of the 2 confirms in the onclick or even the return? and the parameter in delete_confirm? can you show an example please, it is a little hard to follow.

Comment: @Lion789: This sample project demonstrates a `DialogFragment` processing the results of a user filling in a small form: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Dialogs/DialogFragment

Comment: Ok updated my code, but updated code not getting errors but not sure how to implement it now or what tweaks to add... The code you included seems a lot for a simple confirmation box no? Also, trying to keep my code out of the Yes answer box

Comment: @Lion: "The code you included seems a lot for a simple confirmation box no?" -- it is not a simple confirmation box.

Comment: I tried to implement it in a similar fashion, however I am not getting a dialog box to show?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but I think there is a problem with how are you creating the dialog.

You should create a new class for the `Dialog`, then, from wherever you want to open the `Dialog`, you create an instance of that class and show it.

Example taken from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

```
public class FireMissilesDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_fire_missiles)
               .setPositiveButton(R.string.fire, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       // FIRE ZE MISSILES!
                   }
               })
               .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       // User cancelled the dialog
                   }
               });
        // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

Now, as that same page says right after the example: *"Now, when you create an instance of this class and call show() on that object"*

So next, from where you want to open that `Dialog` you should do something like:

```
DialogFragment newFragment = FireMissilesDialogFragment();
newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
```

**More information, that you should have read (and probably did):**

Android's reference to DialogFragment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

Comment: In the end though am I going to have to include the code where it says //Fire Ze Missles! or can I put an event trigger or something in there?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. I have an app with a class that extends `DialogFragment`, and inside that class I created an interface with two methods `onPositiveClick` and `onNegativeClick`, each one is called in the `onClick` method that corresponds.

Then, my main activity (the one that shows the `Dialog`) implements that interface, so when I click on the positive button, the executed code is in my main class. If you think this can be what you want, I can edit my answer, but I'm not sure it is.

Comment: I edited my answer so you can see what I mean, basically trying to do something similar to you but getting an error on the line .show(getFragmentManager -  "The method show(FragmentManager, String) in the type DialogFragment is not applicable for the arguments (FragmentManager, String)"

Comment: I see that in your activity file, in the 4th line you call `newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "missiles");`, but later, around the 14th line you call `dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Confirm_Delete");`, you're mixing the `FragmentManager` class from the support package (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.html) and the other `FragmentManager` (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html), that might be your error now.

Comment: The thing is in he actual class I can use support since it is extending the fragment but in the actual main activity it does not let me use support thats why I changed it to that but I am still getting an error "The method show(FragmentManager, String) in the type DialogFragment is not applicable for the arguments (FragmentManager, String)"

Comment: I still think the problem is because of mixing the support `FragmentManager` with the other one. Try making it to use the same way. That's one of the differences with my code, the other one is that I implement the interface in my main Activity, but as you say, you can't because you are implementing `OnClickListener`, I don't know why, but I guess you need it. Anyways, I don't think I can help if it's not support problem (also, searching your problem on Google seems to agree it's got to do with the support library).

Answer (score 0):

Why does your method require a boolean parameter? On the second line of code you ignore whatever has been passed in anyway, when you set it to false.

```
private boolean delete_confirm() {
        boolean confirm = false;
        // confirm delete
        Builder confirmation = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                // set message, title
        confirmation.setTitle("Delete");
        confirmation.setMessage("Do you want to Delete");
        confirmation.setPositiveButton("Delete",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                            int whichButton) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        confirm = true;

                    }
                 });

        confirmation.setNegativeButton("cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        confirm = false;

                    }
                });

        confirmation.create();
        confirmation.show();
        return confirm;
```

Comment: Ok updated my code, the confirm I was using originally was just the way I would like it to work where it is false unless confirmed... but updated code not getting errors but not sure how to implement it now or what tweaks to add...